# Optical mouse began to act strangely. What can be done?

Tags: mouse, virus

Suddenly my mouse began to behave in a very strange way: it doesn't draw strait lines as it used to do before whenever I moved the mouse more or less straightly, and also the cursor began to move by itself when the mouse remains immovable. Is it a virus? What should I do?

---

Important Addition:

It's an optical mouse

Comment: Is it an optical mouse?

Comment: Ah, I am  sorry, forgot to say, yes it's an optical mouse.

Comment: Is it a wired or wireless mouse?

Comment: similar problem  http://superuser.com/questions/64081/mouse-pointer-moving-on-its-own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tired swapping out the mouse for a known good one?
If this solves the problem then the best solution might be to buy a new mouse.

Comment: I just tried another one (it's also an optical one). Another one is also drawing strange lines, but the cursor doesn't try to "creep" by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is no *dust* or *particles* inside the optical hole under your mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Hey even I got same kind of issue. Its because of faulty mouse, I replaced the mouse and it is working fine. Is this mouse from local company, with low cost? In my case it was.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any bluetooth adapters plugged in? Those could be receiving bluetooth signals from a nearby device.

Comment: No, there aren't