# My cursor will randomly jump around erratically, in a southwest or northeast direction

Tags: mouse

Occasionally the cursor on my laptop will leap to either the bottom left corner or the top right, though it prefers to go to the bottom left. It occasionally just slowly slides, and sometimes can't make up its mind about which of those two corners it wants to go to. The periods in which it does this can range from five seconds to five minutes.

A mild impact on the lower left corner of the keyboard can cause it to jump into this state, and sometimes severe impact on the right will as well, but it does occasionally do this by itself.

It never clicks, and always goes to one of those corners, so it isn't a remote computer. I can still click when it is like this. Using the ball in the center of the keyboard can let me seize back a degree of control, but the trackpad only works when it's moving slowly.

Restarting does not work, and it's been persistently bothering me as I never know when it will begin.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

The laptop is a Dell Latitude D820

Comment: Are you using a mouse? Have you tried another mouse if you are using one? When trying to control with the track ball do you have a mouse plugged in? it sounds like a easy fix but need more info.

Comment: Start by trying to [disable the touchstick](http://joelmansford.wordpress.com/2009/08/19/how-to-disable-the-pointing-stick-touchpad-on-a-dell-latitude-d620-and-probably-d630-d820-d830/), it's possible that it's causing problems.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/454098/why-is-my-mouse-pointer-twitching?rq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/436157/mouse-pointer-on-dell-laptop-moves-on-its-own?rq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/64081/why-is-my-mouse-pointer-moving-on-its-own?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Windows XP or newer and this is a problem with the trackpad then hold the Windows key (bottom left corner of the keyboard)and press "R", this will bring up a run box, type: "devmgmt.msc" in the run box and press enter.

Once the Device Manager populates, expand "Mice and other pointing devices", right click on your trackpad and select "Uninstall", do not check the box to delete driver (uncheck if checked) and reboot the machine.  Windows will (should) install the trackpad driver within five minutes on its own, hopefully this will fix your problem.

Note: Nate's suggestion about touchstick may help or you should look into disabling "tapping"